# how do I update a plone custom policy (e.g. mysite.policy) add-on

Tags: plone

When I first created my Plone (4.1) site, I made a mysite.policy add-on to include some custom users and a custom workflow.

I need to make some corrections to both the workflow and the permissions. I updated the src to include these changes, but updating the package in through the Plone add-on manager (uninstall - install) does not work. As soon as I uninstall the status of all my entries switches to "local policy", so I cannot get the fine-grained status setttings back when I reinstall.

Also, the user permissions do not seem to change. Possibly because they were already created at set-up of the site. But I cannot figure out how to code a change to permissions versus a setup of permissions in the rolemap.xml. I assumed that whatever is in that xml is what rules my plone world, but that does not seem to be working.

So far I cannot find anything about this in the manuals and books I have at hand. Any hints how to solve this? Perhaps the only way to go about this is a series of manual changes through ZMI, but it is so much less elegant to do it that wat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's plenty of options. I'll try to describe a couple of them.

If your changes include only changes in Generic Setup profile of your site policy (*./src/my/site/policy/profile/default/*-files) and you don't want to *automate* the upgrade, you could simply update the profile-files and re-run those specific import steps for your policy:

1. Open ZMI (`site/manage`) for your site and look for `portal_setup`.
2. Select *Import*-tab when on `portal_setup`.
3. Select the profile of your site policy from *Select Profile or Snapshot*-list (the title of your profile is defined by the *registerProfile*-directive in `configure.zcml` or `profiles.zcml` of your policy product).
4. Click to select import steps for *Role / Permission Map* and *Workflow Tool*.
5. From the bottom of the page, deselect *Include dependencies*.
6. Click *Import selected steps*-button.
7. Go to `portal_workflow`-tool on ZMI and *Update security settings*, if your workflow update should modify permission in existing workflow states.

These steps should re-import only the selected import steps of you site policy product's Generic Setup -profile. Re-importing individual steps this way should be quite safe, but be careful: accidental clicks at `portal_setup` screens may have unpredictable consequences.

These steps can also be automated by defining something called Generic Setup *Upgrade Step*.

1. I hope that the default Generic Setup -profile of your site policy product includes `metadata.xml` with line `<version>1</version>`.
2. Update that line to `<version>2</version>`.
3. Open the `zcml`-file with `registerProfile`-directive and, after it, add

   ```
   <genericsetup:upgradeDepends
       source="1" destination="2" sortkey="1"
       title="Upgrade my.site.policy (1 to 2)"
       description="Upgrades my.site.policy's default profile from version version 1 to 2."
       profile="my.site.policy:default"
       import_steps="rolemap workflow"
       run_deps="false"
       />
   ```

These steps should register such an upgrade step from the profile version 1 to 2, which re-imports steps *rolemap* and *workflow* (*rolemap.xml* and *workflows.xml*). You should be able to run the upgrade step from the Plone Site Setup's Add-ons-screen, where there should now be an upgrade button after your installed policy product.

As mentioned by @toutpt, the Collective Developer Manual has [more examples on upgrade steps](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html?highlight=upgradestep#upgrade-steps). If you have ever wondered, why it's recommended to use integers in `metadata.xml`, usually independently from the product's release version number', this is the reason :).

Answer (score 1):

Any changes that need upgrade must be shown by increment the number in profile/default/metadata.xml (keep integer). Next you have to write an upgrade step. It will add an upgrade button in the addons control panel.

Please follow this tutorial to learn how to create an upgrade step: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/genericsetup.html?highlight=upgradestep#upgrade-steps